# How to make an audience Co host by id in agora io in android

Tags: android, agora.io

When a user joined in a stream as an audience I can get his id, I would like to make that specific user a co-host. For example, I  specific user's video will be shown in a mini window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agora RTM SDK to send a signal to that audience. You can implement a logic that when the audience receive that signal, he will call setClientRole method to change this role from audience to host. For more detailed information and code samples, you can refer to this FAQ: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/host_set_role